# Batch output filename to variable

Tags: batch-file

I am currently trying to use batch to grab a specific file name and then place it in a variable since the file name may change but the "client" or "mui" portion will not.

These two lines are what I tried first. using dir to search a path and /b to grab only the name I then filter with "client" or "mui" and that works for finding just the name. But trying to pipe that into a variable didn't work.

```
dir "\\server\path\here" /b | Find "client" | set Client
dir "\server\path\here" /b | Find "mui" | set MUI
```

So I tried my hand at these other items I found during some googling but these didn't work either.

```
FOR "tokens=*" %%a in ('DIR "\\server\path\here\"' /b) do (SET OUTPUT=%%a)
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir \\\server\path\here /b | Find client') do @echo %%i
for /f %%a in ('dir \\server\path\here /B | find "client"') do set FileCount=%%a
```

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

For those who come here later I ended up using

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir \\server\path\here /b ^| Find "client"') do (Set BaseClient=%%i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR "tokens=*" %%a in ('DIR "\\server\path\here\"' /b) do (SET OUTPUT=%%a)
```

should work (if you look for the only or the last file)

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir \\server\path\here /b ^| Find "client"') do @echo %%i
```

you forgot to quote the `find` string (maybe `dir /b /a-d ...` and `find /i "client"` might be a good idea), and the `|` has to be escaped.

```
for /f %%a in ('dir \\server\path\here /B ^| find "client"') do set FileCount=%%a
```

Filecount? You might want `dir /b /a-d ... ^| find /i /c "client"` here.